# Pascal - mysterious field increase

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I'm writing a custom structure manipulation program, and I've got the following types:

```
type
StrLen = 0..MaxLen;
Str = ^StrInst;

StrInst = record
length: StrLen;
data: array [StrPos] of char;
end;
```

Then I've got the following procedure:

```
procedure  ReadStr(var S: Str);
var  pos: StrLen;
begin
      S^.length:=0;
      pos := 0;
      writeln('pos before entering:',pos);
      writeln;
      with  S^  do begin
        repeat
                Inc(pos);
                Read(data[pos]);
        until   (ord(data[pos]) = 13)   or   (pos > MaxLen+1);
        writeln('pos after entering:',pos);
        length := pos-1;
      end;
end;
```

Problem is, when I read into the second object of that type, **pos** variable, and thus the **length** field, is getting a mysterious increase by 1. The following code

```
ReadStr(S1);
ReadStr(S2);
```

outputs (when I input '123' in both cases):

```
 pos before entering:0
 123 
 pos after entering:4

 pos before entering:0 
 123 
 pos after entering:5
```

Will be very gladful, if someone clears situation for me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some possibly relevant parts of the program.  In particular, if this is on Windows then (depending on how you are reading the file) you may have an extra character in the second string because you're stopping at a CR and not processing the following LF.

Comment: Well, I'm not reading any file, input is read into structure's field.

Comment: @Nordvind - However you're reading the value, this seems to be the most plausible explanation. Testing is easy, switch your '13' with '10' and see.. BTW, you're skipping the first element, you'd like to switch places of the 'Inc' and the 'Read'.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz: I thought too that `Read` should come before `Inc`, but then I saw that the array was defined as `data: array [StrPos] of char`, and it is unknown whether `StrPos` identifies a range of indexes that starts with 0, though it is possible that the OP has mistakenly put it instead of `StrLen`, which does start with 0.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that pressing "Enter" key actually inserts two characters instead of one =)
Btw, array is correct, I'm missing StrPos = 1..MaxLen in type definition.